# GeoPandas Clip returns empty dataframe

Tags: geopandas, clip

I have two shapefiles: Boundary.shp and Lines.shp. I want to clip the lines inside one boundary polygon.

```
    import geopandas as gpd
        
    fn_boundary = "D\Boundary.shp"
    fn_aerial = "D\Lines.shp"
    df_boundary = gpd.read_file(fn_boundary)['geometry']
    df_boundary_list = df_boundary.tolist()
    x = df_boundary_list[0]
    df_aerial = gpd.read_file(fn_aerial)
    poly_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame([1], geometry=[x], crs=df_aerial.crs)
    df_aerial_clipped = gpd.clip(df_aerial,poly_gdf)

**>>> print(df_aerial_clipped)

Empty GeoDataFrame
Columns: [Length, Placement, geometry]
Index: []**
```

Why does it return an empty data frame?
This code works fine for another set of shape files. But for these two shape files, it is returning an empty data frame. What is the issue with the shape files? Or is there any mistake in the code??

I have uploaded both the shape files at
this [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1s8-BNMRXnpaIB0lkReb5OJFn79TKWHdu/view?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your shapefiles are in different coordinate systems and you are setting (not reprojecting) the clipped layer to the incorrect system. Change your `crs=df_aerial.crs` to `crs=df_boundary.crs`. If you want the output to be in your `aerial` crs then you could add `df.to_crs()`.

```
import geopandas as gpd
    
fn_boundary = "D:/Downloads/shapes/Boundary.shp"
fn_aerial = "D:/Downloads/shapes/Lines2.shp"
df_aerial = gpd.read_file(fn_aerial)
df_boundary = gpd.read_file(fn_boundary)['geometry']

df_boundary = df_boundary.to_crs(df_aerial.crs)

df_boundary_list = df_boundary.tolist()
x = df_boundary_list[0]
poly_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame([1], geometry=[x], crs=df_aerial.crs)
df_aerial_clipped = gpd.clip(df_aerial,poly_gdf)
print(df_aerial_clipped)
df_aerial_clipped.to_file('D:/Downloads/shapes/out.shp')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
But it still returns an empty DataFrame at my end! :(
Is it returning the clipped features at your end?

Comment: I changed 
"df_boundary.to_crs(df_aerial.crs)"
to
"df_boundary = df_boundary.to_crs(df_aerial.crs)"

It works now :)